# How to remove items from a list in React Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to remove object from a list in react but have no luck. I'm using react hook to maintain state:

```
const [temp, setTemp] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    call service().then(response => {
      let list = response.data.list // [{name:"test"}, {name:"xyz"}]
      setTemp(list); // empty
      handleRemove(name);
      console.log(temp) // empty
  }, []);
  
  
  function handleRemove(name) {
    const newList = temp.filter((item) => item.name !== name);
    console.log("remain lane--"+newList)
    setTemp(newList);
  }
```

I don't know what's happing but it is not setting the temp list.
I tried multiple ways to remove element from the list.

Answer (score 1):

React useState is Async operation and you can not see the update immediately.

Actually your code works fine but you can't see it!. To see the changes that made to the state I changed the code as below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setTemp(list);
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(temp);
}, [temp]);

function handleRemove(s_name) {
  const newList = temp.filter((item) => item.name !== s_name);
  //console.log("remain lane--"+newList);
  setTemp(newList);
}

return (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        handleRemove("blue");
      }}
    >
      Remove 'blue'
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

I put the `handleRemove` function in a button click event to perform this action in different time as you click on it.

Please see the updated code in CodeSandBox:
Here is the CodeSandbox:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-murdock-v140g?from-embed=&file=/src/SomeComponent.js)

Comment: Thanks @Khaled but my object looks like => [{name:"test"}, {name:"xyz"}], so temp = [ {}, {}, {} ]

Comment: I saw your codeSandbox and it is also not working. temp is empty. please update me if you found anything.

Comment: @HiteshKumar in that case I updated the CodeSandbox code for you to explain the react State. See the description in my given answer :)

Comment: Thanks Khaled but my requirement is different, I do not have button, it should do on page load, so I am using useEffect(). OR any solution welcome which will show the updated value.

Comment: @HiteshKumar back to my answer description, on page load your code works fine but you cannot see the log in time and I put the remove method in the button click event for you to understand the life cycle of react

Comment: you are right, we can't do it with state, so using vanilla javascript. Thanks Khaled. I will post my solution

Comment: @HiteshKumar feel free to accept my answer, btw it helps me a lot increase my Reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

In `handleRemove` you have to use `temp.filter` instead of `list.filter`

`list` isn't in the scope of the useEffect so `handleRemove` can't access it, but `temp` can be accessed since it's in the scope above the `useEffect` and `handleRemove`. 
So once you've fetched the data and assigned it to `temp`

`list = temp`

```js
function handleRemove(name) {
    const newList = temp.filter((item) => item.name !== name);
    console.log("remain lane--"+newList)
    setTemp(newList);
  }
```

Comment: that is just typo sorry for that, I updated the code. Thank you